# wordpress wp_script_is done not working on custom scripts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to load something only after a specific script is done loading. [Wordpress provides a method](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is) to detect if a script loaded or not via 'wp_script_is'. When I use the jquery handle with "done" it works but when I use a custom script handle, nothing happens. My code:

```
function my_custom_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script_handle', '/stem_plugins/temp.js', array( 'plugins', 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts' ); 

function include_file() {
  if ( wp_script_is( 'custom_script_handle', 'done' ) ) {
     include('dependent_file.php');
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'include_file' );
```

Interestingly, if I use the 'jQuery' script handle instead of my custom script handle, it works. Or if I use my custom script handle with "enqueued" instead of "done" it also works but I need it to work specifically with "Done".

Comment: What if you add a priority to the `wp_footer` action? `add_action( 'wp_footer', 'include_file', 99 );`

Comment: That did it! Thank you. Please respond with this solution as answer instead of comment and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that your custom script hasn't been printed by the time you run `wp_script_is()`, since you're using the default `add_action()` priority of 10. Adding any priority greater than 10 should solve the issue:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'include_file', 20 );
```